# Diamond Shape Rounded

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

Even tho I am new to Blender, I have tried many techniques posted on stack. However, I can't find a way to make this shape with a solid element (with faces).

[image]

Comment: That's not possible to create with 1 face if you mean that. Subdivided plane is needed which will provide geomtetry available for bending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Steps:

[image]

1. **Subdivide** a **Plane** (<kbd>W</kbd> > **Subdivide**) as much as you need, keep in mind to have vertex in the center of a **Plane**. So you will need odd number.
2. Select vertex in the center.
3. Turn on **Proportional Editing** (you can switch trough different falloffs to get different results).
4. **Scale** down (<kbd>S</kbd>) and increase **Proportional Editing** influence size - <kbd>MouseWheel</kbd>.

Comment: thk really nice